# ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
need a solution for this error

Comment: please add some more context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.